# Sail.JS Styles not applying to all pages?

Tags: javascript, css, sails.js

I'm using Sailsjs **v0.12.4**
with NodeJS **v6.4.0**

I'm trying to apply my `styles (css/js)` to all of my views `(folders)`.
Whatever **I route '/' to**, it renders the styles `(bootstrap, font-awesome)`, but the other `routes/pages` do not render them.

**layout.ejs**

```
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/importer.css">
<!--STYLES END-->
```

Does anyone know a good tutorial for importing stylesheets and scripts best practices? It seems every now and then I get stuck on a importing libraries and it's getting to be a bother.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/views/layout-ejs

Comment: In which page are you adding this ? Do you have a master page ? Or you adding these on each page separately ?

Comment: I'm using Sailsjs Framework (like Rails with Ruby), and the layout.ejs is the "master" page. I'm not sure why bootstrap is ONLY rendering on my '/' route. So if I went to '/user/new' route, it wouldn't have any bootstrap..

Comment: OK try like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/bootstrap.css">` also for other two files.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know whats folder structure and where you have written this code? You need to add it to master page.

Please check console ofr error. Is there anything like 404 not found error? Or any other warnings. Share it with us so we can help to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your css folder in assets folder then if you change your page to example.com/another-page then sails tries to access css files in example.com/another-page/styles/bootstrap.css while they are in example.com/styles/bootstrap.css

In your layout add ../ to your css links. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/importer.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sails uses default `layout.ejs`  in the views folder to render its pages.

sails loads `js, css` files in asset folder automatically to `layout.ejs` on each run. It looks for placeholders

```
<!--STYLES-->

<!--STYLES END-->
```

for css and

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->

<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

for javascript.

Say , you have a route in `routes.js`

```
'get /foo' : 'FooController.bar'
```

and in `FooController.js`, you have an action `bar`

```
bar : function (req, res) {
    return res.view();
}
```

In `views` folder, you should have a file in `foo/bar.ejs`

`res.view()` renders the default `layout.ejs` and replaces `<-% body %>` with contents of `bar.ejs` file.